# Force flag on Bonsai elasticsearch import not working (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I'm following "[Ruby on Rails](https://docs.bonsai.io/docs/ruby-on-rails)" to set-up my Bonsai Elastic Search Heroku add-on, but the `FORCE` flag is not working.

Here's the command from the instructions:

```
heroku run rake environment elasticsearch:import:model CLASS='Company' FORCE=yes
```

And here's the error message:

```
ArgumentError: companies does not exist to be imported into. Use create_index! or the :force option to create it.
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use `:force` instead of `FORCE`?

Comment: Strange, FORCE=yes should have worked. Relevant Ruby code here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-rails/lib/elasticsearch/rails/tasks/import.rb#L63

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use curl to create the index. Something about heroku, possibly, doesn't allow the standard command to work.

For users, you would do something like this: (replacing the username, password, and url....)

`curl -XPUT http://username:password@redwood-12345.us-east-1.bonsai.io/users`

Comment: index created successfu.lly what should i do next ?